# Using bluebird only for organization

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm having a hard time to organize my code, so i decide implement the bluebird in the initialization process, but the only purpuse is organization, so i don't know exactly how to call resolve in one of my process.

I have:

```
Configuration(app).then(Apps).then(Routes)

Configuration -> Turn my configuration object global.
Apps          -> configure the uses, sets and uses of express
Routes        -> create the routes
```

The problem is. How to apply the logic of a new promises in this file:

```
var Apps;

Apps = function(app) {
  app.engine('.html', ejs.renderFile);
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../../client/views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(body.json());
  app.use(body.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  }));
  app.use(cookie());
  app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname, '../../client/public')));
  app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname, '../../client/app')));
  app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', GLOBAL.config.cors.origin);
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', GLOBAL.config.cors.methods);
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', GLOBAL.config.cors.headers);
    next();
  });
  app.use(session({
    secret: '04Eq27Sgg0BDlgfRmarMar1234689007-James-Bond'
  }));
};
```

I don't have any logic like: Do this, if ok call `resolve`, if not, call `reject`. So, is stupid to do this:

```
var Apps;

Apps = function(app) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    app.engine('.html', ejs.renderFile);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../../client/views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(body.json());
    app.use(body.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    }));
    app.use(cookie());
    app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname, '../../client/public')));
    app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname, '../../client/app')));
    app.use(function(request, response, next) {
      response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', GLOBAL.config.cors.origin);
      response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', GLOBAL.config.cors.methods);
      response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', GLOBAL.config.cors.headers);
      next();
    });
    app.use(session({
      secret: '04Eq27Sgg0BDlgfRmarMar1234689007-James-Bond'
    }));  

    resolve()
  }
};
```

My question is. In this case, what can i do???

Comment: There is no need for a `then` callback to return a promise. It can just `return app`

Comment: I really don't get what you are using Bluebird for. Your setup process doesn't even seem to involve anything asynchronous? So just go for `Routes(Apps(Configuration(app)));`

Comment: Promises are for organizing and managing control flow and error handling of asynchronous operations and they are particularly valuable when you have multiple async operations that must be coordinated in some way.  That's pretty much it.  Trying to use promises for non-async code will likely just make things more complicated than need be.

Comment: you just said "is for organizing...". I want organize the code, shouldn't i?

Comment: could you explain better @jfriend00?

Comment: @user98293989823: For organising *asynchronous control flow*. Not for mundane code.

Comment: Promises are for asynchronous operations.  Do you understand what those are?  It also sounds like maybe you should go back and read more about what promises are and what they are useful for because you're trying to use them in a place where they offer no value.  It's kind of like you're saying "Well, I have this hammer, can I open my soda can with it?"  I suppose you could, but it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Yeap, i understand perfectly why use promises, and in my case i know that doesn't offer any value besides organization, thats the point of my question...

Comment: Promises do NOT offer value for organizing non-async operations.  They only make synchronous code more complicated, not less complicated.  They are not a generic code organization tool.  If you really understood what promises offer and are useful for, I think you would already understand that.  That's why I suggested you may need to understand them better.  My advice is to stop trying to organize synchronous code with promises.